# Como alterar o HTML através do TypeScript (Angular 2)?

Tags: angular, typescript

Estou tentando criar um efeito de "maquina de escrever" onde uma letra é inserida após a outra. O código está assim:

TypeScript:

```
TypeWriter() {
    let element = <HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("nome");
    let frase = "Oi tudo bem?";
    let soletra = frase.split('');
    for(let i = 0; i < soletra.length; i++) {
      setTimeout(() => element.innerHTML += soletra[i], 75 * i);
   }
  }
```

HTML:

```
<h3 id="nome"> Split: </h3>
```

O problema é que não está funcionando. A idéia é que cada letra da frase "Olá bom dia" seja inserida no html (element.innerHTML) a cada 75 milissegundos (a multiplicação serve pra que as letras nao sejam inseridas ao mesmo tempo, portanto a letra do vetor 1 será inserida 75 milissegundos + a posicao (75 + 1) depois da letra no vetor 0)

// ATUALIZAÇÃO - Versão sem o RxJS //

TypeScript:

```
  export class Componente1Component implements OnInit {
        frase = '';
        ngOnInit() {

          const soletra = 'Oi tudo bem?'.split('').reverse();
          const soletrar = (a) => {
            this.frase += a;
            if (soletra.length > 0) {
              setTimeout(() => soletrar(soletra.pop()), 75)
            }
          }; 
}
```

HTML: nao alterei

```
<h3 id="nome"> {{ frase }} </h3>
```

Comment: Como já mencionei antes em outra pergunta feita por vc, quando faz **...innerHTML = "letra, 75 * posicao")** vc simplesmente está inserido no elemento o texto letra, 75 * posicao, para realizar o cálculo utilize **`template string`**, o que tbm não sei se garantirá que vai funcionar, pois, me parece que o código não está correto!

Comment: LeAndrade corrigi o for. Se eu faço algo como "  <h3 id="nome"> Split: {{ TypeWriter() }} </h3>) " no HTML, o innerHTML funciona, mas de forma desordenada e infinita

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WesLipe, fiz alguns ajustes utilizando um pouco do RxJS. Veja abaixo o código:

Template

```
<div>{{frase}}</div>
```

Classe

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { from, of } from 'rxjs';
import { delay, concatMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  frase = '';
  ngOnInit() {
     const soletra = 'Oi tudo bem?'.split('');
     from(soletra)
      .pipe(
        concatMap(x => of(x).pipe(delay(75)))
      )
      .subscribe(a => {
       this.frase += a;
      });
   }
}
```

[image: Resultado da execução do código acima]

Comment: cara, funcionou! Muito obrigado. Terei que estudar sobre RxJS pq nao entendi nada do seu codigo kk, agradeço pela colaboração!

Comment: @WesLipe este trecho poderia ser escrito sem o RxJS. Ficaria assim: `const soletra = 'Oi tudo bem?'.split('').reverse(); const soletrar = (a) => { this.frase += a; if (soletra.length > 0) { setTimeout(() => soletrar(soletra.pop()), 75) } };`

Comment: Ola marcelo, obrigado pelo comentario. Tentei reproduzir a sua versão sem o RxJS e nao funcionou, se possivel, poderia me dizer o que fiz de errado? Adicionei na publicação :)

Comment: @WesLipe tudo bem? Adicione `soletrar(soletra.pop());` na última linha do seu método `ngOnInit`, no exemplo que você colocou na publicação. Acredito que só faltou o "start" da função `soletrar`.